# Creating complex landscapes in Blender Game

Tags: modeling, game-engine, particles

Blender Game doesn't have a built in particle system, so I am wondering how I can distribute trees, grass, shrubs, rocks, etc around my world. Should I research how to script my own system, or do most people just hand place every single asset in their game. Or is there a way I can use a particle system, apply it to make each particle actual objects, and then use that in Blender Game?

Comment: For not dinamic creation of the landscapes just use the blender internal particle system in blender render mode, then when the landscape is finished change to blender game.